# Error loading DispatcherServlet's default strategy class

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, dispatcher

I m getting the following exception while trying to deploy the war file on Weblogic 10.3.6 server.

The application is using SPring mvc.

`Error loading DispatcherServlet's default strategy class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.Def
aultHandlerExceptionResolver] for interface [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/bind/MethodArgumentNotValidException
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:766)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerExceptionResolvers(DispatcherServlet.java:604)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:423)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:752)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet$ContextRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:989)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet$ContextRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1)
        at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:97)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:68)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classpath doesn't have `spring-web-x.x.x.jar`, that's why the exception is. Please use Maven build tool for building your Spring MVC project. Add all the necessary dependencies in pom.xml. For spring-web 3.0.4 version, it would be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: resolved the issue. I was using 3.1.0Release jar . But the spring jars in the proj were of the version 3.1.0.RC1.