# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when deploying Spring Boot .war within .ear on Wildfly with other deployments

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm encountering a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when deploying a Spring Boot application as a `.war` file within a `.ear` deployment on Wildfly. The error only occurs when there are other deployments included in the `.ear` file.

However, if I deploy the `.war` file on a fresh Wildfly instance with no other deployments, I don't encounter any issues.

**Details:**

Here's the specific error message I'm seeing:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 142) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."interfaces2.ear"."redacted-kafka-consumer.war".undertow-deployment: 
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."interfaces2.ear"."redacted-kafka-consumer.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing con
dition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.basicErrorController
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.basicErrorController
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.basicErrorController
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear.redacted-kafka-consumer.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.interfaces2.ear.redacted-kafka-consumer.war" from Service Module Loader]
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear.redacted-kafka-consumer.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:246)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear.redacted-kafka-consumer.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:239)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear.redacted-kafka-consumer.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:229)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear.redacted-kafka-consumer.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:182)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear.redacted-kafka-consumer.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:157)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear.redacted-kafka-consumer.war//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/DefaultErrorAttributes (Module "deployment.interfaces2.ear" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
        at deployment.interfaces2.ear//org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
        ... 54 more
```

This error seems to be related to the class `DefaultErrorAttributes` from Spring Framework's `spring-boot-web` module. It appears that the class loader is unable to find the necessary class `HandlerExceptionResolver`, leading to the `NoClassDefFoundError` at runtime.

**Additional Information:**

- **Spring Boot version**: 2.7.11
- **Wildfly version**: 23
- **Java version**: 11

Here are the relevant dependencies from the `pom.xml` file of the `redacted-kafka-consumer` module:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: By default deployments in an ear have access to each other's resources, so you may have version mismatches within the different modules that are causing you misery. Is ear subdeployment isolation turned on or off as documented here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class%20Loading%20in%20WildFly.html ?

Answer (score 1):

"[Error loading DispatcherServlet's default strategy class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20267074/6309)" or "[Please advise to me that Spring MVC Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45453371/6309)" are both pointing to some version discrepancy between modules.

So double-check the current versions loaded by your pom.xml when building your war:

```bash
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

And check if there is any update you might want to consider upgrading to:

```bash
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

Check if an [enforcer](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) would fail your build, using a `DependencyConvergence` rule, when building your deliverable:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <DependencyConvergence />
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```